# How Can Insert Password From Seed to database by bcrypt function my code are show delow

Tags: laravel, insert, passwords, bcrypt

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'role_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'MD.Admin',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt(value:'admin')
        ]);

```
     DB::table('users')->insert([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'name' => 'MD.Author',
        'username' => 'author',
        'email' => 'mahid@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt(value:'auth')
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Please use code format, and explain a clear question. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

change `'password' => bcrypt(value:'auth')` to `'password' => bcrypt('password')`